# why I cant access to value of hidden input element by javascript?

Tags: javascript, input, hidden

I have an page that I cant use value of hidden input in if clause.
and dont print anything in page.
I use this javascript command past days and worke but dont work here.
my code is:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function ch()
{
    alert();
document.write(" brnd = ");
var c=document.getElementById("brnd").value;

document.write(document.getElementById("brnd").value);
document.write(document.forms["br"]["brnd"].value);
}
window.onload=ch();
</script>
</head>

<body >
<form id="br">
    <input type="hidden" id="brnd" value="0000pp"  />
</form>
<p>Page Description.
</p>
<div id="brands" style=""   >
                            <ul style="height:20% !important;width:90% !important;">
                                <li><a href="yat.php" style="color:#000">y.t</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ez.php" style="color:#000">ez</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ami.php" style="color:#000">am</a></li>
                                <li><a href="gr.php" style="color:#000"> group iks</a></li>
                                <li><a href="fr.php" style="color:#000">frtc</a></li>
                                <li><a href="ar.php" style="color:#000">armco</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>

</body>
```

**Where is the problem in your opinion?**

=============================================

**@Rocket Hazmat: thanks for your note.one problem was place of ch.i move ch to after input and work.but have another problem that i dont know how solved. anyway code work now.thanks all.**

Comment: This may just be a typo here, but `document.forms[br"]["brnd"]` is a syntax error.  You're missing a `"`.

Comment: Where is hidden input ?

Comment: I'm pretty sure there are errors in the console. Those errors should help you find out what the issue is.

Comment: If is in another page not here

Comment: excuse me I changed type of input. edit that

Comment: @harix: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/OMBmEJ it is working fine for me.

Comment: @Pbk1303: Because you changed the order of the JS code in relation to the HTML code.

Comment: @Pbk1303: `window.onload=ch();` still isn't correct.  It only works there because the JavaScript code is placed *after* the HTML, so it can find the elements without having to wait for `onload`.

Comment: Oops missed that. Thank u.

Comment: I call ch after form tag but didnt work.

Comment: @Rocket Hazmat: thanks for your note.one problem was place of ch.i move ch to after input and work.but have another problem that i dont know how solved. anyway code work now.thanks all.

Answer (score 2):

```
window.onload=ch();
```

This line will *run* the `ch()` function and set `window.onload` to its *return value*. `ch()` returns `undefined`, so you will not be setting `onload` to anything.

You want to do:

```
window.onload = ch;
```

In JavaScript, functions are like other variables.  You can just pass them around normally.  You use `()` to *call* them.

NOTE: `document.write` should ***never*** be used.  Using it is most likely your other issue here.  Once the page is fully loaded, `document.write` will *destroy* your page.  It will erase it *all* and replace it with whatever you passed.

Because of this, your hidden element would be deleted and therefore you can no longer get its value.

Comment: function execute well and show alert but dont display value of input

Comment: @harix: What do you mean?

Comment: dont display value input in page

Comment: @harix: It's displayed in the console.  If you want to put it on the page, you'll need to append it to the DOM.  P.S. `document.write` is not the correct way to do this.